# new to matlab, trying to plot a vector field using quiver

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot a simple vector field but I'm unsure of the syntax for quiver because it doesn't seem to be working. It's just displaying an empty plot.  I think it has something to do with the ./ but it won't even run when I remove the period.  Thanks

```
v = -5:0.1:5;
[x,y] = meshgrid(v);
u1=(2./x);
u2=(2.*y./(x.^2));
quiver(x,y,u1,u2);
```

Comment: Your code is *syntactically* correct. However, you have a lot of data points causing your arrows to be small in the first place, and for `x=0` your vector field is infinitely large. This probably messes with the auto-scaling of arrows: try `v=linspace(-5,5,10)` (the main point is in the even number of points: this avoids the `x=0`/`y=0` lines.

Comment: thank  you very much that worked.  Although I'm not sure why an even number of points avoids the x = 0 line

Comment: Think of it the other way around: what if you *do* want to include the origin on a symmetric domain? Then you have a point at `x=0`, then a few points, say `n`, up to `xmax`. But due to symmetry you will also have exactly `n` points in the negative region, down to `-xmax`. Together with the origin, you have `2*n+1`, i.e. an odd number of points. The corollary is that if you use an even number of points, you can't hit the origin.

Comment: ahh I see now.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your vector field is infinitely large at `x=0`, which messes with the auto-scaling of arrows. Try avoiding the coordinate axes, for instance by using `v=linspace(-5,5,10);`. By using an ever number of points on a symmetric domain, you ensure that `x=0` and `y=0` are never used.

Result using this `v`:

[image: fixed]

Comment: @jvriesem thank you:) Although I'd note that (1) OP won't see this ping here, (2) my answer is community wiki because the question is so simple that I don't believe rep should be earned for answering it (but my answer felt like a bit more than a comment, and I wanted to include the figure). So the accept would mainly signal that the problem is solved.